# High pressure deformation of metals

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, crystals, metals, x-ray-crystallography

Does copper undergo elastic recovery after being exposed to high pressures (above 30 GPa in a diamond anvil) at room temperature?

Comment: Purely hydrostatic, or shear, or what???